# How so sum a column based on another column?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this snippet of code below and I would like to sum the `num` column when the `notification_date` is grouped by date? I would also like the `num` column to DESC
is this possible?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,desc

results = spark.sql("SELECT lhd_2010_name, lhd_2010_code, notification_date, num FROM cases_df")    
    
results.show()
spark.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spark syntax it looks good, you have to modify the SQL query as below:

1. If you only need sum and date columns:

   ```sql
   select * from 
   ( select notification_date,sum(num) as s_num 
     from cases_d 
     group by notification_date ) a 
   order by s_num desc
   ```
2. If you need all the fields:

   ```sql
   select b.lhd_2010_name,b.lhd_2010_code,a.notification_date,a.s_num 
   from (select notification_date,sum(num) as s_num 
         from cases_d 
         group by notification_date) a 
   join cases_d b
   on a.notification_date=b.notification_date
   order by s_num desc
   ```

Comment: Thank you @AviG I will try this out